# In depth resources about the Cardano sidechain research and vision

Tags: sidechains

During the 2021 Summit Aggelos [briefly mentions](https://youtu.be/pdZSltPNA-0?t=908) a future of Cardano which includes sidechains which will, among other things, enable integration with other blockchains.

Does anyone have in depth resources (eg: whitepapers, IOHK blog posts, etc) which elaborate on this idea so that I can learn more?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Hydra](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/299.pdf).

Comment: Hydra is a state channel (like lightning), not a sidechain, right?

Comment: According to Charles, the Catalyst Voting System is running on a sidechain.

Comment: AFAIU, Hydra is the mechanism that will enable cross-chain communication. Sidechains would be a single usecase for Hydra.